# Código Sql Syntax Highlighting

Tags: delphi

Olá, alguém conhece algum componente (ou função) capaz de destacar certas partes de um determinado texto (Highlighting).

Estou implementando um sistema onde o usuário poderá executar alguns comandos SQL's tais como `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` e etc, então gostaria de deixar algo mais 'bonito' o `TMemo` é apenas texto puro.

O Highlighting que busco implementar pode ser algo básico como deixar em Negrito ou Destacar com cor diferente os principais comandos.

Comment: Onde esse texto será exibido?

Comment: Atualmente o usuário esta escrevendo no TMemo. A saída do texto é o que menos nos interessa entende, temos TMemo, TRich etc etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Componente <kbd>[SynEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/)</kbd>, vai resolver seu problema. Atualmente utilizo inclusive para [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), porém tem suporte para varias linguagens, como:[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [cobol](/questions/tagged/cobol), [js](/questions/tagged/js), [php](/questions/tagged/php), etc.

**Como utilizar SynMemo:**

Após instalar o componente, repare que vai surgir duas novas abas **SynEdit** e **SynEdit Highlighters**, então vá até a primeira aba e adicione o componente `TSynMemo` em seu `form`, assim como um `TMemo`, após feito isso, vá ate a segunda aba e selecione o componente para fazer o Highlighter em seu `TSynMemo`, no seu caso o `TSynSQLSyn`, e adicione ao `Form`.

Adicione a propriedade Highlighter do TSynMemo que está em seu Form, o `TSynSQLSyn`, e já estará funcionando.

Você também pode alterar as cores, negrito, itálico, etc., do Highlighter, diretamente no componente `TSynSQLSyn`.

---

**Edição:**
Como uma opção paga, temos o `TAdvMemo`, produzido pela [TMS Software](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/default.asp), com suporte para Delphi 7, 2007, 2009, 2010, XE, XE2, XE3, XE4, XE5, XE6, XE7, XE8 e 10 Seattle.

Realizei o teste e a maneira de utilizar é igual, porém a nomenclatura muda, ficando assim:

**Como utilizar o AdvMemo:**

Após instalar o componente, repare que vai surgir uma Aba **TMS MEMO**, então adicione o componente `TAdvMemo` em seu `form`, assim como um `TMemo`, após feito isso, vá até a aba e selecione o componente para fazer o Highlighter em seu `TAdvMemo`, no seu caso o `AdvSQLMemoStyler`, e adicione ao `Form`.

Adicione na propriedade SyntaxStyle do TSynMemo que está em seu Form, o `TSynSQLSyn`, e já estará funcionando.

Comment: @Júnior, dessa maneira não resolve?

Comment: +1 Resolve sim, estou procurando uma solução e ate mesmo usando alguns recursos das unit desse componente, a ideia é não ficar preso a componentes. Se você viu, este ate então não é atualizado a muito tempo, o medo de ficar preso a isto é grande, pois, aconteceu e acontece todo dia com diversos componentes! Logo posto resultados!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira adicionei uma opção paga ;) veja se atente.